# Perl Deleting all text after a string in a variable

Tags: arrays, perl

I have a array that contains numbers as such:

```
@content = (0,1,3,4,5,6,7,8);
```

Given the number 3, i would like to have the array erase any values that are 3 and less changing the array `@content` into:

```
@content = (4,5,6,7,8);
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html) to filter a list of values:

```
my @content = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);

@content = grep {$_ > 3} @content;

print "@content\n";
```

Outputs:

```
4 5 6 7 8
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're willing to make a copy along the way, investigate [`grep`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html). Otherwise:

```
my @content = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8);

my $deleteUpTo = 3;

for ( my $i = @content - 1; $i >= 0; --$i )
{
    if ($content[$i] <= $deleteUpTo)
    {
        splice(@content, $i, 1);
    }
}

print join(', ', @content);
```

> 4, 5, 6, 7, 8

Comment: `for ( my $i = @content - 1; $i >= 0; --$i )` simplifies to `for ( my $i = @content; $i--; )`

Comment: Yes, it does. In fact there are all *sorts* of ways to make the code less readable to a novice.

Comment: Right, so let's avoid needless complexities.